# Postgresql subquery contains errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am taking a course on SQL and this is my Exercise. I broke it down into two steps (inner and outer statement). In the third step I want to combine the previous steps into one query with a subquery. But it is not working. Can someone help me fix this (and possibly even make me understand this..)? Thank you so much!

Exercise: [Your team wants to know what is the average amount paid in the list of the top 5 customers who have paid the highest total amounts]
The top 5 customers who have paid the highest total amounts have already been queried with this query:

```
SELECT B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country,
SUM(amount)  AS total_payment 
FROM payment A
INNER JOIN customer B ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id
INNER JOIN address C ON B.address_id = C.address_id
INNER JOIN city D ON C.city_id = D.city_id
INNER JOIN country E ON D.country_id=E.country_id
WHERE D.city IN ('Aurora', 'Atlixco', 'Xintai','Adoni', 'Dhule (Dhulia)', 'Kurashiki', 'Pingxiang', 'Sivas', 'Celaya', 'So Leopoldo') 
GROUP BY B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country
```

This should be made into a subquery. It should have the alias total_amount_paid.
Write an outer statement to calculate the average amount paid.
Add your subquery to the outer statement. It will go in either the SELECT, WHERE, or FROM clause. (Hint: When referring to the subquery in your outer statement, make sure to use the subquery’s alias, “total_amount_paid”.)

Step ONE (inner statement)

```
(SELECT B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country,
SUM(amount)  AS total_payment 
FROM payment A
INNER JOIN customer B ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id
INNER JOIN address C ON B.address_id = C.address_id
INNER JOIN city D ON C.city_id = D.city_id
INNER JOIN country E ON D.country_id=E.country_id
WHERE D.city IN ('Aurora', 'Atlixco', 'Xintai','Adoni', 'Dhule (Dhulia)', 'Kurashiki', 'Pingxiang', 'Sivas', 'Celaya', 'So Leopoldo') 
GROUP BY B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country) AS total_amount_paid
```

Step TWO (outer statement)

```
SELECT B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country,
AVG(total_amount_paid) AS avg_amount_paid
GROUP BY avg_amount_paid
```

Step THREE (combined query, comes out with a lot of errors that I can't fix because I don't understand what I am doing, basically)

```
SELECT AVG (total_amount_paid) as average.total_amount_paid
FROM
(SELECT B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country,
SUM(amount)  AS total_payment 
FROM payment A
INNER JOIN customer B ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id
INNER JOIN address C ON B.address_id = C.address_id
INNER JOIN city D ON C.city_id = D.city_id
INNER JOIN country E ON D.country_id=E.country_id
WHERE D.city IN ('Aurora', 'Atlixco', 'Xintai','Adoni', 'Dhule (Dhulia)', 'Kurashiki', 'Pingxiang', 'Sivas', 'Celaya', 'So Leopoldo') 
GROUP BY B.customer_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, D.city, E.country) AS total_amount_paid
GROUP BY average.total_amount_paid
```

Probably it is also a mess because of the GROUP BY statements? To be honest, I don't understand what GROUP BY even means.. :D

Comment: "To be honest, I don't understand what GROUP BY even means", what don't you understand about it?

Comment: I don't know what's the actual use. Is it there to define which columns are shown in my data output and in which order?

Comment: This isn't the place for an sql tutorial. But if you want to know how was paid, do you want per costumer or per order, that is your group by

Comment: I know, I am just grateful for any help because I learn by myself and sometimes the information is not presented in the way I can grasp it so I am always at the lookout for someone who puts it in different words so it "clicks". This was such a moment, thank you!

Comment: Show the expected result, along with the test data over which that calculation is performed.  You have an ambiguous question that needs to be resolved before you can really attempt to solve the problem.  Which average did the question call for?  Is it the average of amounts paid per customer (1 row per customer in the result), for the top 5 customers (by total sum)?  Is it the average of the top 5 customer sums (one row in the result)?  There are a few other possible meanings.  Do you know which?

Comment: If it's just to add the average per customer, along with the total sums per customer, you're overcomplicating the SQL, and you don't really need city detail at all.  You could even remove the customer names detail in the initial attempt.  Keep it very simple and build toward the answer.

Comment: If you dont know what the GROUP BY means: leave it out, and see what happens. (the `SUM(amount)` will become invalid ...)